# QImage to QPixmap Convertion Parameter Error after QT 6.2 Update at PyQT

Tags: python, qimage, qpixmap, qt6, pyqt6

I was using "QPixmap(qt_image)" to convert from QImage to QPixmap at PyQT5. After getting updates of QT6 and PyQT6, I get error at as below;

```
TypeError: QPixmap(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QImage'
```

So changed usage of typecasting as QPixmap.fromImage(qt_image) and now getting this;

```
TypeError: fromImage(QImage, flags: Qt.ImageConversionFlag = Qt.AutoColor): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QImage'
```

There are some reference links that I used to get information about QT6 QPixmap;

- [doc-snapshots.qt.io - QPixmap](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-6.2/qpixmap.html#fromImage)

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Right now I can't, because downgraded the version to 5. Thanks for inform.